# Right to left check arrow

Tags: android, icons, drawable, right-to-left, android-vectordrawable

I need right to left check arrow like the second arrow in picture for my background drawable in android

[check arrow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USADw.png)

```
   I need to rotate left to right check arrow vector icon 
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:width="24dp"
           android:height="24dp"
          android:viewportWidth="24.0"
          android:viewportHeight="24.0"
            >
        <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
         android:pathData="M9,16.2L4.8,12l-1.4,1.4L9,19 21,7l-     1.4,-1.4L9,16.2z"/>

    </vector>
```

Comment: share your xml , so that we can see

Comment: Yes, please show your effort so far.

Comment: I dont have any xml but I sent the Image

Comment: don't do lyk this , otherwise everone will downvote this question ,you have to first try by urself and then put your effort with question

Comment: thanks for your help I first tried to rotate left to right vector check arrow but I couldnt fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to flip an existing `VectorDrawable` like this is to scale it using a *negative number*.

The `<group>` tag of a VectorDrawable is where we can play with the scaleX and scaleY properties. Using these properties, a value of 1 is full size and a value of 0 is scaled down to nothing; 2 would be double the size, 0.5 would be half size etc.

If we use a negative number it shrinks all the way down to zero, then starts increasing in size in the opposite direction. So in your example, to flip the check-mark horizontally we can use:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <group
        android:pivotX="12"
        android:scaleX="-1">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:pathData="M9,16.2L4.8,12l-1.4,1.4L9,19 21,7l-1.4,-1.4L9,16.2z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

We wrapped the path in a `<group>` tag and gave it a `scaleX` value of -1, meaning the normal size but in the opposite direction. Also the `pivotX` value is 12, this is because the full width of your viewport is 24, and we want to flip the icon right around the centre line.

Which transforms this:

[image: normal check-mark]

Into this:

[image: flipped check-mark]

*Edit to add:*

I see that your question is tagged with `right-to-left`, as in for languages which are read from right to left. The answer above may not be what you wanted in this case, so here's an alternative:

If you want the `VectorDrawable` to appear the original way when being used on a left-to-right device, but the opposite way on a right-to-left device then there is a specific property to enable this: autoMirrored.

By setting autoMirrored to true the drawable will show the default way in left-to-right mode but will be horizontally flipped when in right-to-left mode(but note this is only supported on API 19 and up):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:autoMirrored="true">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M9,16.2L4.8,12l-1.4,1.4L9,19 21,7l-1.4,-1.4L9,16.2z" />

</vector>
```

Comment: @mozhi, I've edited this answer as I realise your question may be about compatibility with right-to-left layouts rather than just editing an individual drawable.

Comment: Thanks alot.I really appreciate you